# Calculate VAT helper method

Tags: c#, helper

Was looking online for a method to calculate VAT, but can't seem to find it.

```
decimal subTotal = FinalInvoice.Hold_Back_Value;
decimal VAT = //calculate vat at 20% for subtotal using helper method
decimal TOTAL = subtotal + VAT;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple percentage calculation.

```
public decimal CalculateVat(decimal value)
{
  return (value / 100) * 20;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest you to add the 20% to the net by plain math:

```
decimal vat = 0.2;
decimal tot = net * (1 + vat);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
decimal subTotal = FinalInvoice.Hold_Back_Value;
decimal vat  = 1.2;
decimal Total = vat * subTotal;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to multiply by 20% (expressed as a fraction):

```
decimal vat = subTotal * 0.2;
```