# VAT at my cost by 25% VAT

Tags: c#, asp.net

I must add 25% VAT on top of the price specified when you create a product.

How do I add the 25% tax on to the price?

i have tried the following:

```
string pris = TextBoxpris.Text;

decimal prisMoms = pris * 0.25;
```

I found the inspiration in this question -> [Calculate VAT helper method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133091/calculate-vat-helper-method)

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?  Converting a string to a number?  Adding 25%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse what's in the text box.

```
decimal parsed = 0, prisMoms = 0;
var canParse = decimal.TryParse(TextBoxpris.Text, out parsed);

if(canParse)
{
  prisMoms = parsed + (parsed * 0.25m);
}
```

Comment: It indicates that there is an error here `(parsed * 0.25)`

Comment: Try `parsed * .25m` and see if that works

Comment: I like when someone tells: _there is an error_ and don't tell you the error. Time to use a crystal ball.

Comment: Yeaaa its work for me now!. And Thanks for it game! :)

Comment: Not really a crystal ball. It could only be that the compiler sees `0.25` as a double and not a decimal. Adding the `m` fixes that easily.

Comment: @IronMan84 thanks for u remember me on its! i have do it now!